# how to uninstall or remove a deno script?

Tags: deno

I have installed a `deno` script by running :

`deno install https://deno.land/std/examples/welcome.ts`

How do I uninstall this script now ?

Is there a subcommand in deno that can uninstall installed scripts ?

Comment: deno use to have a uninstall command but they removed it, but you can do it with rm ;  rm $(which foo)

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately `deno uninstall` was [removed](https://github.com/denoland/deno_std/pull/512#issuecomment-504005054)

The current solution is to do:

```
rm $(which file_server)
```

But an [issue regarding](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/3139) `uninstall` was reopened 6 days ago, so it may come back in the near future.

Answer (score 3):

Remove it manually from `$DENO_DIR/bin` (defaults to `$HOME/.deno/bin`)

E.g. on Windows, I ran the following in PowerShell:

```
PS > rm $HOME/.deno/bin/myscript.cmd
```